# EpiServer: Convert String to XHTMLString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, episerver

I'm currently using EpiServer 7.5 with ASP.Net MVC.

Basically, I'm defining a property inside a model which needs to be of type XHtmlString. What I wish to do inside the model is set a default value for the XHtmlString, but since this is represented by a string, how can I do this?

Here's an example in code - this is my model:

```
[Required]
[Display(
    Name = "Thank you message",
    Order = 1)]
public virtual XhtmlString ThankYouMessage{ get; set; }
```

Now, later on the code, I simply want to set the default value of this ThankYouMessage type to a string.

```
ThankYouMessage = "Default thank you message";
```

This won't work because ThankYouMessage is an object type of XHtmlString and I obviously can't set this to a type of string.

I think it has something to do with the [XHtmlStringConverter](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7/3324e9c0-3468-6964-59b4-2942cb814dc3) but I can't figure this out - any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to convert the string into an XhtmlString as that is the property type. This is simply done by creating a new XhtmlString object.

```
   ThankYouMessage  = new XhtmlString("Default thank you message")
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would work instead of the way the OP tried?

Comment: @JohnOdom The OP's attempt fails because there is no implicit conversion from string to `XhtmlString`. An `XhtmlString` must be created explicitly.